# Assigning weights to edges of a graph so that the minimum spanning tree's weight is maximal

Tags: graph-theory

How can we assign weights to the edges of a complete graph on $n$ vertices such that

- the sum of weights is equal to $1$ and
- the weight of the minimum spanning tree is maximal?

What will be the weight of the minimum spanning tree after this assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a graph $G$ of $n$ vertices, there are totally ${n \choose 2}$ edges and [$n^{n-2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) spanning trees. Denote the set of spanning trees as $\mathcal{T} = \{T_1, T_2, \cdots, T_\ell\}$, where $\ell = n^{n-2}$, and for a tree $T_i$, its weight as $\omega(T_i)$. It is not hard to observe by symmetry that each edge of $G$ is contained in *exactly* $n^{n-2}(n-1)/{n \choose 2}$ spanning trees. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\ell \omega(T_i) = n^{n-2}(n-1)/{n \choose 2}
$$
implying
$$
\min_i \{\omega(T_1), \omega(T_2), \cdots, \omega(T_\ell)\} \leq (n-1) / {n \choose 2}
$$
That is, the weight of the minimum spanning tree of $G$ is at most $(n - 1) / {n \choose 2}$. We can achieve this upper bound by setting the weights of all edges as $1 / {n\choose 2}$.